# how to get option menu in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the code which is electron is give basic gui

```
const electron = require("electron");
const Main = require("electron/main");
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = electron;
const path = require("path");

let MainWindow;

app.on("ready", function () {
  MainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
  MainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
  MainWindow.setMenu(null);
});
```

I want to add help menu and also the file option..

Comment: `const menu = new Menu(); MainWindow.setMenu(menu)`?